# how to change date format depending on language - SSRS

Tags: date, reporting-services, format

I need to change date format to `dd/MM/yyyy` if the language of the user is french, and to `MM/dd/yyyy` if it's another language.
I need the variable that define the language of the user to put it here :

```
=IIF(language = "fr", Format(Fields!ValueDate.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", Format(Fields!ValueDate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

I need the variable language or another method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameter for Language.

Select the textbox then on Properties Pane go to Format.

Then on expression use this formula:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Language = "FR", "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new Parameter with Name - **Language**. Pass it as parameter from the site. *(While you are passing ensure that it is same as Parameter name)*

For example: If you have passed the parameter **Language** then it must be same in Reports parameter with **Language**

Now, use below expression.

```
=IIF(UCase(Parameters!Language.Value) = "FR",Format(Fields!ValueDate.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy"),Format(Fields!ValueDate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy"))
```